# How to sort a list of dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Input data:

```
results= [
        {
      "timestamp_datetime": "2014-03-31 18:10:00 UTC",
      "job_id": 5,
      "processor_utilization_percentage": 72
    },
        {
      "timestamp_datetime": "2014-03-31 18:20:00 UTC",
      "job_id": 2,
      "processor_utilization_percentage": 60
    },
        {
      "timestamp_datetime": "2014-03-30 18:20:00 UTC",
      "job_id": 2,
      "processor_utilization_percentage": 0
    }]
```

Output has to be sorted like below, grouping by `job_id` in ascending order:

```
newresult = {
    '2':[{ "timestamp_datetime": "2014-03-31 18:20:00 UTC",
            "processor_utilization_percentage": 60},

          {"timestamp_datetime": "2014-03-30 18:20:00 UTC",
          "processor_utilization_percentage": 0},]

    '5':[{
          "timestamp_datetime": "2014-03-31 18:10:00 UTC",
          "processor_utilization_percentage": 72},
        ],
    }
```

What is pythonic way to do this?

Comment: You are *grouping* your output; do you need the groups to be sorted still? Your timestapms are all the same, are you sorting on `processor_utilization_percentage` at all?

Comment: no output should be dictionary of list where key should be job_ids only

Comment: Dictionaries *have no order*, you can only **group** your data by `job_id`. The keys in `newresult` are not listed in any order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are *grouping*; this is easiest with a [`collections.defaultdict()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

newresult = defaultdict(list)

for entry in result:
    job_id = entry.pop('job_id')
    newresult[job_id].append(entry)
```

`newresult` is a dictionary and these are not ordered; if you need to access job ids in ascending order, sort the keys as you list them:

```
for job_id in sorted(newresult):
    # loops over the job ids in ascending order.
    for job in newresult[job_id]:
        # entries per job id
```

Comment: The OP made an edit that the output should be grouped by `job_id` *in ascending order*, so you'll need add a sort at the end.

Comment: @BioGeek: except that dictionaries are *not ordered*.

Comment: thanks @MartijnPieters tryed ur solution geting below error lease not i am using python 3.0 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#240>", line 1, in <module>
    newresult = defaultdict(list)
TypeError: first argument must be callable

Comment: @sagar: you assigned something else to `list`; use `del list` first so that `list` once again refers to the built-in type.

Comment: @sagar: never use `list` as a variable in your code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the `results` by their `job_id`:

```
from itertools import groupby
new_results = {k: list(g) for k, g in groupby(results, key=lambda d: d["job_id"])}
```

The result is a dictionary, i.e. it has no particular order. If you want to iterate the values in ascending order, you can just do something like this:

```
for key in sorted(new_results):
    entries = new_results[key]
    # do something with entries
```

---

Update: as Martijn points out, this requires the `results` list to be sorted by the `job_id`s (as it is in your example), otherwise entries might be lost.

Comment: This only works if the list is sorted on `job_id` first.

Comment: I mean the *input*, `results`, needs to be sorted by `job_id` for `groupby` to work. `results` is a list of dictionaries, if there is a dictionary at index 0 with `'job_id': 1`, and another at index 5, with other entries with different `'job_id'` values in between, you end up with just *one* `'jobid': 1` entry in your output.

Comment: From the `groupby` documentation: *Generally, the iterable needs to already be sorted on the same key function*. Using `defaultdict` grouping is a O(N) operation, with sorting and `groupby` it's `O(NlogN)`. `groupby` is great if the input is already sorted, of course.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Didn't know that, thanks for pointing out. I'll add this to my answer and leave it here, so others don't make the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you really didn't want the the job_id in the newresult:

```
from collections import defaultdict
newresult = defaultdict(list)
for result in results:
    job_id = result['job_id']
    newresult[job_id].append( 
        {'timestamp_datetime':result['timestamp_datetime'],
         'processor_utilization_percentage':result['processor_utilization_percentage']}
        )
#print newresult
```

I don't really see a way to do this with a dictionary comprehension, but I'm sure there's someone out there with more experience in doing that sort of thing who could pull it off.  This is pretty straightforward, though.

Comment: You can do it with a list comprehension and `itertools.groupby()` but then you need to sort `results` first; not worth it unless that list is always already sorted on `job_id`.